# Как правильно внедрять зависимости классов Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

*Помогите понять, где я ошибаюсь. Вроде все делаю правильно !*

Нужно расширить функционал класса:

```
use custom\class\Finder;
class BaseLoginForm extends Model
{
    /** @var Finder */
    protected $finder;

    /**
     * @param Finder $finder
     * @param array  $config
     */
    public function __construct(Finder $finder, $config = [])
    {
        $this->finder = $finder;
        parent::__construct($config);
    }
}
```

делаю так:

```
use own\class\Finder;
class LoginForm extends BaseLoginForm
{
    /** @var Finder */
    protected $finder;

    /**
     * @param Finder $finder
     * @param array  $config
     */
    public function __construct(Finder $finder, $config = [])
    {
        $this->finder = $finder;
        parent::__construct($finder, $config);

    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что, после того как я делаю так - переменная `$finder = null !`

**Возможно `Finder` класс нужно где то зарегистрировать что бы `Yii` знало откуда внедрять зависимость ????? Помогите разобраться** !

Comment: Можно чуть побольше кода? Добавьте момент создания класса и получения значения переменной, а то не совсем понятно.

Comment: @Pa3Py6aka, спасибо за отклик. Вся проблема в том, что мне нужно использовать методы родительского класса, но с другим обектом `Finder` . И вся проблема в том (как мне кажется), что когда я делаю так (пример в вопросе) yii не знает как использовать класс `Finder`, из-за  того, что по-сути это нидрение зависимостей, а я не зарегистрировал свой объект для использование сервис контейнером. Как это правильно сделать в yii? И возможно, что проблема и правда из-за этого?

Comment: @Maybe_V вы как класс вызываете потом? Вы предполагаете что если вы в `__construct()` указали некий класс, то он сам туда будет передан?

Comment: @Bookin, Да я так думал - но понял, что мои суждения ошибочны. После того как конструктор принимает этот класс - его присваивают переменной $finder. В том и моя проблема, что я не знаю как это правильно сделать в yii.

Comment: Вообще у вас должно выдавать ошибку при создании класса `LoginForm` - вы ему передаёте при создании класс `\own\class\Finder`, он создаётся, вызывается родительский construct - в нём вы передаёте этот же `\own\class\Finder`, но ведь `BaseLoginForm` требует `\custom\class\Finder` - совершенно другой класс. Сделайте в `BaseLoginForm` в construct необязательным параметр `$finder = null`, и в `LoginForm` в construct вызовите просто `parent::__construct()`, либо при создании `LoginForm` передавайте ему два разных `Finder`

Comment: @Pa3Py6aka, но мой `Finder` наследуеться от `\custom\class\Finder`. Разве по принципам ООП  он не должен приниматься  как потомок ?

Comment: Если наследуется то да, ошибки не будет. Но тогда должно всё работать, и Yii тут вообще не касается. В каком месте у вас `$finder = null` ?

Comment: @Pa3Py6aka, все таки есть проблема и с YII функционалом. Нашел в модуле который расширяю такой код http://pastebin.com/zjncF4GQ. Меняю в  Yii::$container->setSingleton(Finder::className()) на путь к своему классу  - все работает. Подскажите, как правильно сделать в своем модуле это. Сделал так http://pastebin.com/5YSsZRK7 но результат нет, возможно его нужно подключить к модулю ?